# Database Project; Add object to schema

Tags: visual-studio-2013, database-project

I'm creating a database project is VS2013. I am manually building up the database as and when the objects are required (it's basically a gradual copy from an existing database). I have done imports to a database project from an actual database and I'm trying to follow the same project structure (i.e. [Schema Name Folder] > [Tables Folder] > [Actual Table Script File]).

The issue I am having is that when I add a new table, regardless of where in the project tree, it will use the default `dbo` schema and the only way I can change the schema of a given object is to change the `T-SQL` of the table's script file which is a slow and error-prone solution. This is even worse if you include the 'Include schema name in file name' option in the database properties as you would have to rename each object you create.

I must be missing something here, is there a way to create an object in a specific schema?

Comment: Have you tried using the "SQL Server Object Explorer" against your project to manage items? I tend to avoid "schema name in file name" as it should be in the right schema folder in the first place. However, it does need to be correct in the actual SQL. The folder structure is more of a guideline than anything else.

Is there a reason you can't import the entire database into a project and work from there?

Comment: @PeterSchott Thanks for your suggestion, the "SQL Server Object Explorer" has the same issue unfortunately. The reason I can't import the entire database is because it is in such a state that I've decided it will be the best solution to start from the start and just pull in the good bits into the new project.

Comment: Got it - in that case, the only way to get that correct is to make sure you have the right schema defined in your code. If you get things in folders, you can look at them in a text editor outside of the IDE pretty easily and verify the schemas that way, but there's no definite way to do that to my knowledge except to type it in correctly. It does seem odd that this can't be picked up on in some way in the IDE.

Comment: @PeterSchott I have come to the same conclusion, seems a strange omission. You can write that into an answer if you want as it seems to be valid.

Comment: Came across this today from Jamie Thomson - maybe this can help? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2014/09/24/sql-server-object-explorer-10-days-of-ssdt-day-6.aspx